# Why is the soft keyboard being hidden on resume?

Tags: android

I have code like the following to immediately show the soft keyboard when entering my app:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    ...

    myEditText.requestFocus();
    myEditText.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(myEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }   
    }, 100);

    ...

}
```

However, on the Android 2.1 emulator, the keyboard appears and then immediately disappears. If I make the delay longer, like 1000, it reliably appears. On an Android 4.0 emulator, a delay of 100 reliably shows the keyboard, but shorter delays do not.

Does anyone know who might be hiding the keyboard? Is there a reliable way to prevent it? If not, is there a delay I can use to guarantee that the keyboard will show?

Comment: Did you try "SHOW_FORCED" instead of "SHOW_IMPLICIT"?This will indicate the user will hide the IMM explicitly.

Comment: I did try that and it does reliably make the keyboard appear. But then if I hit the home button, it goes to the home screen and leaves the keyboard open (on 2.1). So I was hoping for a more elegant solution than having to explicitly hide the keyboard during onPause

Comment: what is your `windowSoftInputMode` for your activity set to in your manifest?

Comment: oy... you are developing for 2.1? <<headache ensues>>

Comment: In your onPause() function you can explicitly suppress the keyboard. But a word of advice: don't do it. Let the system handle it. Have the view auto-request focus. By adding a delayed runnable you are also introducing a lot of potential for error into your code. Most importantly, this is nothing more than a suggestion to the system. The implementation/vendor doesn't have to acknowledge it.

Comment: I wasn't setting windowSoftInputMode. If I set it to stateUnchanged, it fixes the problem, but then I suppose I need to also hide the keyboard if I don't need it (the showing of the keyboard is actually wrapped in an 'if' block that I omitted from the code snippet above).

Comment: @Travis Android platform increasing performance for every new release. Android 2.1 emulator take more time to show keyboard because of its performance. Who is hiding the keyboard? Android 2.1 takes some time to show keyboard that why it appear to hiding to you.

Comment: One other thing I just remembered is probably relevant: I'm using the Swype keyboard.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand you correctly, I think you can remove the following code in your `onResume()`:

```
myEditText.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(myEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }   
}, 100);
```

And simply use `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"` for your Activity in the manifest.

Comment: Admittedly this would work, however in the situation here the keyboard is not always visible I'm interested to know why the `showSoftInput` method does not work.

Comment: I omitted it from the question, but I'm actually only putting focus on the box and showing the keyboard under certain conditions...it's wrapped in an if block

Comment: I need to say that, whenever I'm looking for solution I always end up with this approach.  +1

Answer (score 5):

I think what you are seeing is Android identifying the view that should get focus by default and giving it focus (which hides your keyboard).  Setting your delay longer or shorter just makes it so your code runs before or after that focus is set.  You could figure out what view is getting focus by default, and if you don't want it to ever have focus, set it as focusable false and focusableInTouchMode false.  If it does need to have focus at some point, you could set an onFocusChanged listener, and when it gets focus the first time, post your runnable(without delay) to give the focus to the EditText and open the keyboard.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable explanation as to why the keyboard is being closed.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Daniel Smith and @Cookster.

<strike>This was happening because I did not set a windowSoftInputMode in my manifest, so it was using the default value (stateUnspecified), which hid the keyboard on startup. Apparently, that setting is applied after some delay on resume, and so my call to show the keyboard only worked if my delay was longer than the built-in delay to hide it.</strike>

To fix, I set windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged" and then I always either hide or show the keyboard in onResume. I also removed the delay, which was no longer necessary once the built-in hiding was not happening.

Never mind, that mitigated the problem (it lets me reduce the delay), but it didn't fix it completely. There is something very nondeterministic about this, and the keyboard is no longer appearing if I don't use the delay. However, if I reintroduce a delay of about 100ms, the keyboard seems to show up about 90% of the time, which puts me back where I started: why is this happening and what's a safe delay?

Answer (score 0):

put this code in **onRun()** in **onResume()** method:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
                      Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

**[Edit]**

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    text.requestFocus();

    text.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(text, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
        }   
    }, 100);
    text.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
                      Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(text.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }   
    }, 200);
}
```